# How to manage a site trying out different technologies?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, ruby-on-rails, node-js

I'm a complete newbie to web hosting. I only have programming skills, but I'd like to acquire a domain.  Then I'd even like to have the chance to manage different technologies for hosting web sites and applications.

I mean, I don't only want to try the Apache, PHP and MySQL stack but try out with node.js and Ruby on Rails. These might be subdomains and each correspond to different technologies.

What is the suggested setup for using so many technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most server technologies can be integrated with Apache.  It is so popular largely because it is so flexible and configurable.  Here is how you have to handle the technologies you mention with Apache:

- PHP:  Install a module in Apache that will serve PHP pages such as mod_php5.  Place .php files into the web server root and they will be executed by the webserver
- MySQL: You can call this from pretty much any language that you end up using.  You'll just need the libraries to connect to it.
- node.js: Run the node.js server on a separate port from Apache.  Use mod_proxy as a reverse proxy to serve it through Apache.
- Ruby on Rails: Just like node.js, run it on a separate port and use a reverse proxy

Comment: But what when I'm acquiring the hosting and server service from a third party?

Comment: You'll need to find a host that allows you to install all the software you'll need.  I don't think you'll find shared hosting that supports all the cutting edge tech you want to experiment with. Try Amazon's AWS or a virtual private server (VPS).